# Interstitial ad is not showing up after webview is loaded on android?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I have implemented interstitial admob ads on my android app with java. When ad is loaded before the webview the interstitial shows correctly but if it is loaded after webview loads then interstitial ads become irresponsive i.e cannot be closed. In short, If webview is loaded before onAdLoaded method of interstitial admob ad then interstitial ad does not shows up.

Please suggest appropriate solution for this. Thanks

Admob interstitial code:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAd.load(
            getContext(),
            "ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy",
            adRequest,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                    // an ad is loaded.
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    Log.d("TAG", "onAdLoaded");
                    mInterstitialAd.show(getActivity());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onAdLoaded()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                            new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                    // show it a second time.
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed trending videos.");

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                                    // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                                    // show it a second time.
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                    Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
                                }


                            });
```

Code used for displaying webview:

```
{
        String urllink = "https://www.example.com.com/";
        // Save the web view
        webView = (VideoEnabledWebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        
        webView.onPause();    // This will pause videos and needs to be called for EVERY WebView you create
        webView.pauseTimers(); // This will pause JavaScript and stop_btn for ALL WebViews and only needs to be called once to affect all WebViews
        // Initialize the VideoEnabledWebChromeClient and set event handlers
        View nonVideoLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.nonVideoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
        ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
        //noinspection all
        View loadingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_loading_video, null); // Your own view, read class comments
        webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, loadingView, webView) // See all available constructors...
        {
            // Subscribe to standard events, such as onProgressChanged()...
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                // Your code...
            }
        };
        webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
            {
                // Your code to handle the full-screen change, for example showing and hiding the title bar. Example:
                if (fullscreen)
                {
                    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
                    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                    getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                    {
                        //noinspection all
                        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
                    attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                    getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                    {
                        //noinspection all
                        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
        // Call private class InsideWebViewClient
        webView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
        extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        extraHeaders.put("Set-Cookie","HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");
        webView.loadUrl(urllink,extraHeaders);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by removing all references to `pauseTimers()`